# Can blocking of matplotlib's mainloop be limited to a single window/figure?--i.e., fig.show(blocking=True)

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive

I have a time history of images (2 + 1)D arrays that I take various slices of and examine using `ipython` and each view is a matplotlib figure.

I have a custom class that uses matplotlib widgets (specifically a Slider) to allow an interactive window to open and view the images frame by frame as selected by the Slider.  The widget works fine, but uses the `plt.show()` command to block, which is also fine until I'm done with the widget.

In order for control to pass back to the ipython command line, I have to close all matplotlib figures--I would like to be able to only close the window associated with the widget.  Is there some method to enable this functionality?
Something like `fig.show(blocking=True)` would be what I imagine I want, i.e. limit the blocking of the GUI mainloop to only look for plt.close() of that window, but that does not appear to be currently implemented.

@ImportanceOfBeingEarnest, thanks for the response.  I've added the code I use for the viewer widget.  To initialize the object, you just need to provide a 3D array of [frames (t), y, x] values.  i.e.

`randomData = np.random.rand((5,5,5))`

```
class showFrames(object):
def __init__(self, timeData):
    self.data = timeData   # 3D array of t, y, x values
    self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(1)
    self.im = None
    self.frameStr = None
    self.start()

def start(self):
    # initialize GUI
    Tmin = self.data.min()
    Tmax = self.data.max()
    frameInit = self.data.shape[0] - 1
    self.im = self.ax.imshow(self.data[frameInit])
    self.im.set_clim(Tmin, Tmax)
    self.fig.colorbar(self.im)
    self.frameStr = self.ax.text(0.1, 0.1, '', transform=self.ax.transAxes, color='white')
    axis_color = 'yellow'
    # Add frame and radius slider for tweaking the parameters
    frame_slider_ax  = self.fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
    frame_slider = Slider(frame_slider_ax, 'Frame', 0, frameInit, valinit=frameInit)
    frame_slider.on_changed(self.frame_slider_on_changed)
    plt.show()

def frame_slider_on_changed(self, i):
    self.im.set_data(self.data[int(i)])
    self.frameStr.set_text(str(int(i)))
    self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Using IPython you should be able to work completely in interactive mode, without blocking anything.

Comment: If I don't block, then the GUI cannot interact with the slider widget and allow the redraw of images.  i.e, changing the ```plt.show()``` to ```fig.show()``` eliminates the GUI functionality

Comment: I'd be happy to investigate this a little further if you can provide a [mcve] of the problem. To answer your initial question though: No there is no partial blocking possible with pyplot.

Comment: Added code for widget.  Thanks for any insights you can provide

Comment: Make sure you hold on to instances you create. I.e. `self.slider=Slider(...)` instead of `slider=Slider(...)`. This ensures that even if the function returns due to non-blocking behaviour, your instance of `Slider` will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Wow! There ya go.  With that small change regarding Slider, it works as non-blocking so I can view as desired.  If you want to post, your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Slider` instance is being garbage collected because you don't retain a reference to it.

From the [`Slider` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/widgets_api.html#matplotlib.widgets.Slider):

> For the slider to remain responsive you must maintain a reference to it.

In this case `self.slider=Slider(...)` instead of `slider=Slider(...)`.

Comment: changed plt.show() to fig.show() with your suggestion and worked just like I wanted. Thanks.